# getting parsed json value

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I am trying to utilize bcrypt to check the hashes saved in my db for passwords, but the json response is currently returning below:

```
[
    {
        "password": "$2a$10$8/o1McdQ24pL5MU7dkbhmewkjne83M2duPKp0cb6uowWvOPS"
    }
]
```

This is causing an error on the bcrypt compare, because it is comparing that entire response instead of just the hash inside of it.  How can I get just the value of the hash in my response?  Below is my code:

```
app.get('/checkHash/:username/:pass', function(req, res) {
    console.log('below is the data');
    console.log(req.params);
    var pass = req.params.pass

        var createPromise = interact.getHash(req.params.username);
        //did promise
        createPromise.then(function(createResponse) {  
            //below checks to see if the password value matches the hash
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(pass, createResponse)) {
                //this means that the hashes are the same for user login
                res.json("yes");
            } else {
                //this means that the password hashes didn't match
                res.json("no");
         } 
        }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is apparently an object array. If you just want to compare the first result of your array, you have to pass the index to your array.

```
app.get('/checkHash/:username/:pass', function(req, res) {
    console.log('below is the data');
    console.log(req.params);
    var pass = req.params.pass

        var createPromise = interact.getHash(req.params.username);
        //did promise
        createPromise.then(function(createResponse) {  
            //below checks to see if the password value matches the hash
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(pass, createResponse[0].password)) {
                //this means that the hashes are the same for user login
                res.json("yes");
            } else {
                //this means that the password hashes didn't match
                res.json("no");
         } 
        }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: this still returns the entire json object for password, I am looking for just the string value of the password: `"$2a$10$8/o1McdQ24pL5MU7dkbhmewkjne83M2duPKp0cb6uowWvOPS"`

Comment: Then you just need to access the object's property. Either with `createResponse[0].password` or `createResponse[0]['password']`. Updated the answer